# How to get XYZ euler rotation of 3DView?

Tags: python, transforms, mathematics, matrix

I'd like to extract the user view orientation of the current *3DView*. Since I didn't find a direct command to get it, my approach would be to take its matrix using `bpy.context.region_data.view_matrix.transposed()` and somehow convert it to a Euler rotation (ignoring its location), but I don't know how to do it.

Note that I'm not talking about a camera object but the user view.

Comment: Converting a matrix to euler is as simple as `mat.to_euler()`. Assuming your matrix is in the space you want, that should do the trick.

Comment: Wow that was so much simpler than I expected. Tank you

Answer (score 1):

`bpy.context.region_data.view_matrix.transposed().to_euler()`

Tanks HENDRIX, that was pretty simple

Comment: Just pasting a line, is not really helpful.

Comment: @brockmann If more information is needed, then tell them what kind of additional information you expect.